# VB.net project upgraded to 2.0 from 1.1 : Controls added to aspx page do not appear in aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have tried using drag n drop to place the control as well as simplely adding it to the page manually but neither results in a web control property being defined in the code behind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed a difference between 1.1 and 2.0. If you're in a web application project you can click, in the Solution Explorer pane, on the + sign before the .aspx. There should be a .designer file in which you can see the type and name of the controls you have on your page.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I resolved it by creating a new page under .net 2.0 which then had the correct style of page.